# Accessing BigBlueButton behind a restrictive firewall that prevents outgoing UDP connections

Tags: webrtc, html5-video, html5-audio, freeswitch, bigbluebutton

We have installed a COURN server referring to the https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/setup-turn-server.html#Configure_TURN_. But even with this, we are not able to access the BBB service within the University LAN protected with a restrictive firewall.

Please find the following diagram to illustrate the environment. Looking for your suggestions to solve this issue. We are banging our heads against this wall for some time now.

[image]

Comment: I never used TURN server, but what I can say that you can not access VoIP resources with just 3 ports. Based on my knowledge TURN server is more like a proxy and user must have access to it without restriction(UDP ports should be open), but in your case you just open 3 ports toward TURN and obviously it will not work. I would recommend to open SNGREP or any other similar utility and analyze what ports are being used during VoIP call and then you can get a bit more understanding how all of this works.

Answer (score 1):

From your university network, can you open https://test.bigbluebutton.org/ in a Google Chrome browser, and check whether you can access audio/video without any 1007/1020 errors?

If yes, then check your Turn server config again and ensure your BBB server can use it.

Otherwise, check whether your university firewall allows connections on TCP ports 80 and 443 and UDP ports 16384 - 32768.

Comment: In the same situation. I'll try this solution. Hope it works. 
One question, I'll have to allow UDP ports 16384 - 32768 on the clinet machine right?

Comment: You will have to allow UDP ports 16384 - 32768 on the server where you are running BigBlueButton